# varnish demon error: libvarnish.so.1 not found

Tags: ubuntu, varnish

In order to try out varnish for an upcoming project I installed it on an ubuntu server using this tutorial: http://varnish-cache.org/wiki/InstallationOnUbuntuDapper

The build process worked without any errors, but I cant start the varnish demon. I always get the error message

`varnishd: error while loading shared libraries: libvarnish.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

But `/usr/local/lib/libvarnish.so.1` clearly exists.

How can I tell varnish to look in that directory and load the library?

**UPDATE**

To answer the questions of [cd34](https://serverfault.com/questions/131349/varnish-demon-error-libvarnish-so-1-not-found/131382#131382)

```
    ldd `which varnishd`
```

outputs:

```
    linux-vdso.so.2 =>  (0x00007fff0a360000)
    libvarnish.so.1 => not found
    libvarnishcompat.so.1 => not found
    libvcl.so.1 => /usr/local/lib/libvcl.so.1 (0x00007f2a6fcaf000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f2a6faab000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f2a6f88f000)
    libnsl.so.1 => /lib/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007f2a6f675000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007f2a6f3f1000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2a6f082000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f2a6fec7000)
```

*Do you have varnish in two places on the machine, one from a previous attempt?* 

-> No, varnish is only installed once

*Are you using 2.1.0 which was recently released?*

Yes, I am using the most recent version

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try running `sudo ldconfig` to rebuild the library cache.

Answer (score 0):

```
ldd `which varnishd`
```

Where is varnish looking for the libraries?  Do you have varnish in two places on the machine, one from a previous attempt?  Did you specify any directory paths when you did ./configure ?

Are you using 2.1.0 which was recently released?

Comment: Good questions and thanks for your answer, please see my edit.

Comment: ls -al /usr/local/lib/libvarnish.so.1

if that doesn't find it, try:

find / -name libvarnish.so.1 -print
find / -name libvarnishcompat.so.1 -print

is /usr/local/lib/libvarnish.so.1 a symlink that points to an invalid file?

Answer (score 0):

Try running sudo ldconfig to rebuild the library cache.

helpt me to thankz...