# Varnish on Debian - libvarnish.so.1 not found

Tags: debian, varnish

I'm trying to install Varnish on Debian 6.0.3 and am getting the following error when I try to start the server

`/usr/sbin/varnishd: error while loading shared libraries: libvarnish.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Runnig `ldd 'which varnish'` tells me this:

```
libvarnish.so.1 => not found
libvarnishcompat.so.1 => not found
```

I also found [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/131349/varnish-demon-error-libvarnish-so-1-not-found) on the same topic, but my problem is that the file really is missing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to run:

```
apt-get --reinstall install libvarnish1
```

Comment: `libvarnish1 is already the newest version.`

Comment: run command "updatedb", then run "locate libvarnish.so.1", and tell me what output you get.

Comment: Removed all varnish files, installed varnish again and the files are there now. Starting varnish words. Thanks for your input!